# Are return types considered as rvalues?

Tags: c++

Just a simple question, i am trying to simulate a bad practice when it comes to returning `&&`. I am aware that it's a bad practice.

Here is an example

```
//dummy is just an empty class
dummy && crashtest(){
    dummy temp;
    return std::move(temp);

}


int main() {
    dummy && k = crashtest();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a bad practice because `k` now holds a reference to the destructed `temp` inside the function.

I tried a different approach by doing something like this inside my `main`:

```
dummy l; //generate temp
dummy && k =  std::move(l); //return value
dummy && d = k; // copy
```

though `l` won't really be destroyed, how come it won't let me compile? I get an error saying that i am trying to bind an lvalue. isn't it the same as what happens in function? From my understanding, what happened in function was:

temp is created -> std::move(temp) -> return type `dummy&&` receives it -> `k` is equalized to the return type temporary.

I need clarification. Is the return type considered an `rvalue` ?

Bonus question: what happens if an rvalue reference variable is equalized to an rvalue reference variable? `&&lhs = &&rhs`, does lhs takes the rhs reference?

Comment: For a different view: replace the `&&` by `&` and drop the `std::move()` command. If you understand this case, you'll also the one in your question. With respect to the lifetime of your objects, it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning an rvalue reference from a function will most likely cause a dangling reference(the reference exists, but the temporary object that it refers to has been destroyed).
This is actually called an xvalue(an "eXpiring" value) in the standard.